# Tkinter update polygon points on mouse click

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to update the polygon on each mouse click. The below code redraw new polygon when new position is obtained from mouse click. I want to update the polygon or get new one (delete old one). How to do it. Here is the complete as suggested. Tkinter library of python is used.

```
import math
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import Image, ImageTk

coord=[]  # for saving coord of each click position

Dict_Polygons={}   # Dictionary for saving polygons
list_of_points=[]

# Function to get the co-ordianates of  mouse clicked position
def draw_polygons(event):
    mouse_xy = (event.x, event.y)
    func_Draw_polygons(mouse_xy)  


# Function to draw polygon
def func_Draw_polygons(mouse_xy):
    center_x, center_y = mouse_xy

    #draw dot over position which is clicked
    x1, y1 = (center_x - 1), (center_y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (center_x + 1), (center_y + 1)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='green', outline='green', width=5)

    # add clicked positions to list
    list_of_points.append(mouse_xy)

    numberofPoint=len(list_of_points)
    # Draw polygon
    if numberofPoint>2:

        poly=canvas.create_polygon(list_of_points, fill='', outline='green', width=2)
        canvas.coords(poly,)

    elif numberofPoint==2 :
        print('line')
        canvas.create_line(list_of_points)
    else:
        print('dot')


  #  ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon((list_of_points), fill=None, outline=None)

    print(list_of_points)

##########################################################################
# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':

        root = tk.Tk()
    # Input image
        img = Image.open("e.png")

    # Draw canvas for input image to pop up image for clicks
        filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        canvas = Canvas(root,height=img.size[0],width=img.size[0])
        canvas.image = filename
        canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=filename)
        canvas.pack()
    # bind function to canvas to generate event
        canvas.bind("<Button 3>", draw_polygons)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Please have a look now. Thank You.

Comment: `closest_centroid` isn't defined anywhere in the code yet it is being added to a list.

Comment: I simplified the code by deleting a lot of code except this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you any closer to your solution? It re-draws based on the list of points each time a new point is added to the list.

```
import math
#change to tkinter for python3
from Tkinter import *
#from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
#import Image, ImageTk

coord=[]  # for saving coord of each click position

Dict_Polygons={}   # Dictionary for saving polygons
list_of_points=[]
poly = None

# Function to get the co-ordianates of  mouse clicked position
def draw_polygons(event):
    mouse_xy = (event.x, event.y)
    func_Draw_polygons(mouse_xy)  


# Function to draw polygon
def func_Draw_polygons(mouse_xy):
    global poly, list_of_points
    center_x, center_y = mouse_xy
    canvas.delete(ALL)

    list_of_points.append((center_x, center_y))

    for pt in list_of_points:
        x, y =  pt
        #draw dot over position which is clicked
        x1, y1 = (x - 1), (y - 1)
        x2, y2 = (x + 1), (y + 1)
        canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='green', outline='green', width=5)

    # add clicked positions to list


    numberofPoint=len(list_of_points)
    # Draw polygon
    if numberofPoint>2:
        poly=canvas.create_polygon(list_of_points, fill='', outline='green', width=2)
    elif numberofPoint==2 :
        print('line')
        canvas.create_line(list_of_points)
    else:
        print('dot')


  #  ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon((list_of_points), fill=None, outline=None)

    print(list_of_points)

##########################################################################
# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()


    canvas = Canvas(root,height=200,width=200)

    canvas.pack()
    # bind function to canvas to generate event
    canvas.bind("<Button 3>", draw_polygons)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, it is not closer to the solution I wish. So, is there any way to update list_of_points dynamically, and redraw the polygon by deleting the old one.

Comment: That's exactly what this code does. Deletes the polygon, adds a new point to the list and redraws the polygon.

Comment: I am getting the error "referenced before assignment".

Comment: @johnTahir With what variable and on which line of code?