# Draw open polygon in Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How do I draw an open polygon in Tkinter canvas?

I've been playing with `create_polygon` option, but that does not seem to have a capability to not close it. I'm writing something where you can draw a polygon, smooth it, and than close it with double click.

Comment: Use `create_line()` which accepts list of points.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044836/tkinter-update-polygon-points-on-mouse-click  @scotty3785